# How to see CSS boxes in firefox inspector

Tags: html, css, firefox

From http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#line-box.

After reading above page, i just found out an HTML element can be turned into zero or multiple boxes.

The page gives an example: li element is transformed into multiple boxes.

In firefox browser, i have opened up inspector and choose "box model" tab, and tried to inspect that li element.

But there is only one box in "box model" section, according to above URL, there are multiple boxes for the li element, but why i can not see or select those extra boxes?

like those line-boxes, how to see/debug them?

Comment: Requirement not clear. Please, do elaborate it more.

Comment: if I inspect an `li` element in firefox and switch to box model, I see the box surrounded by 3 boxes (padding, border, margin)... not sure what you expect to see?

Comment: @Navnish Bhardwaj, as the page said, li element has 4 boxes associated, one block level, one line box, 2 inline box, how can i inspect those 4 boxes in browser.

Comment: @ Simon Hänisch, is padding a box?

Comment: I think you can't visualize the boxes... the box model only shows the box of one element and its padding, border, margin... it doesn't show the boxes included in that box.

Comment: no padding/border/margin is not a box, sorry can't edit the comment anymore

Comment: This is working as Canvas http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/stack.png

Comment: Do you have anywhere live example for these boxes, so I can try inspecting for you

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. " i just found out an HTML element can be turned into zero or multiple boxes." this is not really a thing. The `linebox` doesn't create new elements it defines how lines are distributed inside an element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that my mistake, that URL is a working draft, not been implemented.